# What else can i use instead of 'setInterval' in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, try-catch, intervals

I have a function where I am using setIntevals but I would like to use something else instead  as I am implementing background processes and intervals do not work in background.

Here is the simplified code I am using(can't post all of it because is waay too long):

```
this.carInterval = setInterval(() => {
   try{
   ///
   }
  catch{
   ////
   },5000);
}
```

Comment: What about setTimeout?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Intervals and timers do not work in background, it doesn't matter how you do it, they just don't work.

Comment: Have you tried setTimeout(() => console.log('do something'), 5000)?

Comment: @MatheusFrez Intervals and timers do not work in background.

Comment: If intervals and timers don’t work then, in JavaScript at least, there’s not much else you can do... not in my limited knowledge at least